# How can I say "I had to part ways" when I don't want to think like someone anymore?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I want to say that I don't want to think like Paul anymore, so I have written this:

"I had to part ways in thinking from Paul"

Does that capture the gist?

Comment: Paul and I had to part ways. Period.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to say:

> "I had to part ways with Paul in my thinking"

Typically you use "part ways with" instead of "part ways from", although I think both constructs can be recognized correctly.

If you say

> "I had to part ways in thinking from Paul"

it's unclear whether you're parting from Paul or whether you're parting your thinking somehow.